# What is the "good" calling convention for a DLL?

Tags: c++, vba, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to write a DLL function (in C++) that I can call from Excel VBA. I keep getting `Run-time error '49': Bad DLL calling convention` when I try to call a function with parameters. I have no issue calling a function without parameters. I believe I covered most of the obvious gotchas (I verified function names using `> dumpbin /EXPORTS` for example) so I truly must be missing something fundamental. I post the code below.

I get the same errors on both Windows 7 and Windows 10. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and MS Excel 2007 and 2016 (2007 on the 7 box, 2016 on the 10 box). I am using `__declspec` and `extern "C"` syntax as inspired by [this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp)

MathLibrary.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API int add_integers(int a, int b);

extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API int get_integer();
```

MathLibrary.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MathLibrary.h"


int add_integers(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int get_integer()
{
    return 69;
}
```

VBA Module functions and definition

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function add_integers Lib "..\MathLibrary.dll" (ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function get_integer Lib "..\MathLibrary.dll" () As Integer

Public Function test()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    x = 42
    y = 27

    ' this returns 69
    i = get_integer()

    ' this throws Run-time error 49
    i = add_integers(x, y)

End Function
```

Comment: When you use VBA the you care a wholeheckoflot about `__stdcall`.  Since it doesn't support anything else.  Unless you use 64-bit code, then it doesn't matter.  It is the future, like plastics and robotics.

Comment: [wow that was easy.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235591(v=vs.60).aspx)  not sure why it took me so long to figure it out...

I'm curious though why I've seen some kernal functions (`Sleep` for example) that don't have that funny syntax

Comment: OS functions, like Sleep, are stdcall.  That is why it is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) for pointing me in the [right direction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235591(v=vs.60).aspx). If define the functions with `__stdcall` it works.

MathLibrary.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API int __stdcall add_integers(int a, int b);

extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API int __stdcall get_integer();
```

MathLibrary.cpp

```
/* MathLibrary.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application. */
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MathLibrary.h"


int __stdcall add_integers(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int __stdcall get_integer()
{
    return 69;
}
```

The functions are exported as "_add_integers@8" and "_get_integer@0" and I call them as such from VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function add_integers Lib "..\MathLibrary.dll" Alias "_add_integers@8" (ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function get_integer Lib "..\MathLibrary.dll" Alias "_get_integer@0" () As Integer

Public Function test()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    x = 42
    y = 27

    ' this returns 69
    i = get_integer()

    ' this also returns 69
    i = add_integers(x, y)

End Function
```